# Help identifying a similar sunroof "spring" part/replacement

Tags: bmw, part-identification, sunroof

I am looking for help to identify a similar part/replacement for this flat spring strip. It is a retrofit manual, thus the part is not in the ETK or any other parts catalogue that I can see.
The part is marked "F" in the image below, and is called a "spring" ("feder" in the German version). The large part (A) that it attaches to is the sunroof shade, and the "spring" is screwed on top of it (ie roof-side). It is a metal flat spring (likely made from spring steel) from what I can tell.
[image: EBA extract]
Here is another picture of it, in the flesh:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What firm created the retrofit sunroof? They'll be identified in the installation manual, and they'll know. Have you asked them?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I don't see what the question is here, you seem to have identified the part already.

Comment: It's a webasto kit, they stop communication once it's clear the part was sold by BMW, and refer to them. BMW can't help as they no longer sell this kit, and didn't do much in terms of design input.

Comment: As, so you are trying to identify the original manufacturer's part number of the part with the same function? That didn't come out in your question.

Comment: sorry, I'm trying to find a similar/replacement part, eg if Webasto used this design elsewhere. Their part numbering is a mystery to me, so I'm not even going there, just relying on imagery in case somebody spots a familiar shape